# tkinter .update() function slowing down performance over time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having issues with performance, I am calling a big function that takes a while to run and the screen won't update unless I call .`update()` from that function. I know it is `.update()` because the function ran fine when I removed it.

```
def BigFunct():
    while(True):
       #this is where the code WOULD be
       app.update()


app = Tk()


app.title("Example")
app.geometry("770x700") 

Button1 = Button(app, text="Call Funct", command=BigFunct)
Button1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you run code that takes a lot of time to execute between calls to `update()`, it will still make your app sluggish. If the code being run does not need to utilize tkinter, consider running it in a separate thread (and not calling `update()` from it).

Comment: I tried it with asyncio and threading, for some reason only threading works not asyncio.

Comment: It ought to be possible with `asyncio` too, but without seeing the code and known what `BigFunct()` is actually doing, it's impossible to say what you may have done wrong.